# Linux kernel regmap irq handler has an issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have been working on irq handlers using the regmap irq chip implementation.
I have seen that there is high incosistency with the irq handlers execution. Especially if the irq is generated continuously during suspend. The irq chokes and never clears the interrupt source i.e handler never runs at times. Even if the handler runs half way and the system sleeps, it does not continue on resume.

Its creating serious issues. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regmap entirely uses threaded irqs. In addition, I was using i2c calls in the nested calls which are again threaded irqs. Due to this, I would always remain in user space and not in irq context. I2c tranfer has schedule in it and that brings in a completely different execution flow. In addition, there were problems in wake enabling the irq.